# Boundary of zero set of smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, smooth-functions

Does the boundary of the zero set of a smooth function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ always have Lebesgue measure zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The zero set of a smooth function can be any closed subset (a theorem of Whitney). So now you are asking if the boundary of a closed subset has always Legesgue measure $0$. Not always, as experimenting with some Cantor type subsets reveals.

Comment: I understand. Am I correct in thinking this can also arise when f is required to be non-negative?

Comment: @daon: Yes, you are correct.