# Zero set of a smooth function (Reference/Example Reques)

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, smooth-functions

In reference to this question:

[Boundary of zero set of smooth function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533888/boundary-of-zero-set-of-smooth-function)

I'm looking for a reference to the "theorem of Whitney" which says that the zero set of a smooth function can be any closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Alternatively, a  construction of a smooth function which vanishes on a *fat* cantor set would also be great!

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179445/non-zero-smooth-functions-vanishing-on-a-cantor-set

Comment: Wow this link has both answers - thanks!